# How do I get the index number from the array in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following code how do I get the number for the index/row that is 'd'?

```
    var docs = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(dataset)
      .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d["Identifier"]})
        .attr("num", function(d) { return d}) // this
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d3.time.format.iso.parse(d["UserDate"]))})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return xScale(d3.time.format.iso.parse(d["UserDate"]))});
```

Answer (score 6):

simply use :

```
function(d,i){ ... }
```

e.g.

```
.attr('id', function(d,i){return 'item'+i;})
```